# Table colspan fix

Tags: html, css, html-table

Under here two codepens. In each of them you'll notice a green area. In one of them this is done with a table, in the other one divs were used. Also notice the behavior when you resize your window.

**Table codepen**:http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Kmdca?editors=110 and **div codepen**:http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tDhIG?editors=110
So the competing parts are:

**table codepen**:

```
<table class="information_table">
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><span class="prodinfo_title">Auteur: </span>Onbekend</td>
    <td><span class="prodinfo_title">Formaat: </span>37 x 23 cm</td>
    <td><span class="prodinfo_title">Prijs: </span>1900</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><span class="prodinfo_title">Uitgever: </span>Pieter Jacob Paets Jan Moerentorf</td>
    <td><span class="prodinfo_title">Jaar v. uitgave: </span>1646</td>
    <td><span class="prodinfo_title">Aantal pg: </span>4 + 1265 +1 +468</td>    
    </tr>
    </table>
```

vs

**div codepen**:

```
<div class="info_box">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column big"><span class="prodinfo_title">Auteur: </span>Onbekend</div>
    <div class="column"><span class="prodinfo_title">Formaat: </span>37 x 23 cm</div>
    <div class="column"><span class="prodinfo_title">Prijs: </span>1900</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column big"><span class="prodinfo_title">Uitgever: </span>Pieter Jacob Paets Jan Moerentorf</div>
    <div class="column"><span class="prodinfo_title">Jaar v. uitgave: </span>1646</div>
    <div class="column"><span class="prodinfo_title">Aantal pg: </span>4 + 1265 +1 +468</div>
  </div>         
</div>
```

What I want to achieve is that

- the green area as shown in the table codepen is divided in 4 equal parts, in which the first column exists of 2 of these parts. Neither really solves this as the **table codepen** does not use the full available space and the **div codepen** does not automatically divide the space correctly.
- The red text in the 2 green areas are on the same horizontal spot like in the **div codepen** when it is on its maximum width (this behaviour unless on small sizes, where 1 box jumps under the floated)
- When resized all the info jumps as a whole under the floated div like in the **table codepen**. The **div codepen** does not do this correctly. Also 1 row has to stay 1 row, the **div codepen** also does not manage to do this
- The red text in a row is on the same vertical height. The **div codepen** does not do this

So currently the **table codepen** is behaving best, except for the horizontally alligning of the red text in different **tables** and making optional use of the available space.

Comment: Add `white-space:nowrap` to your .column class in your DIV-based layout to make it work better.

Comment: @Diodeus :This causes the words to cross into eachother!

Comment: The available space issue can be fixed in the table codepen by adding a calculated width to the .information_table: `width:calc(100%-100px)` (the 100px is 90px for the width of the product_float + 10px for its margin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final solution came from csstricks: http://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/colspan-problem/page/2/ .
We dropped the table due to wrong semantics and managed to get the desired effect through lists:
http://codepen.io/wolfcry911/pen/mJsrp

HTML

```
<ul>
     <li><h4>Auteur:</h4>Amelotto Della Houssaia</li>
     <li><h4>Formaat:</h4>/</li>
     <li><h4>Prijs:</h4>200</li>
     <li><h4>Uitgever:</h4>Pietro Del Martello</li>
     <li><h4>Jaar v. uitgave:</h4>0</li>
     <li><h4>Aantal pg:</h4>246+242</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul {
 margin: 10px 0 10px 100px;
 padding: 0;
 background: #6C9;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 font-size: 0.8em;
 list-style: none;
  }

li {
 float: left;
 width: 25%;
 padding: 4px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

li h4 {
 color: #b02a0a;
 float: left;
 margin: 0 4px 0 0;
}

li:nth-child(3n+1) {
 width: 50%;
 clear: left;
}
```